# What is/are the EOF in ubuntu and also about Kernighan and Ritchie

Tags: c, ubuntu, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have started learning C and I have also started using Ubuntu. I am writing the codes in vim through the terminal. I have been studying from Kernighan and Ritchie. Here is the code -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int c;
 while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
 putchar(c);
 return 0;
 }
```

Now, my question is :-

1. The program stops if i press ctrl+z , but it also terminates if i press ctrl+D , when i read about it online it says ctrl+z is the EOF in windows and ctrl+d in linux. Does it mean that both of them are EOF in linux? If so , what are the other EOF ?
2. Is it okay to have such complex questions in the first chapter of this book ? or am I supposed to just read through it and these kind of thoughts will get cleared as I read on ?

Comment: Actually, in Ubuntu, which uses the bash shell, typing ^Z runs the [shell's suspend command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Basics) which simply puts the running program in the background. It's still running, though. So ^Z really has nothing to do with EOF in Ubuntu. You can see this if you add e.g. a call to `printf()` after the loop in your program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two different things are happening.

Typing Control-Z in Windows or Control-D in Linux triggers an end-of-file condition and causes `getchar()` to return the value `EOF`.

Typing Control-Z in Linux does something different: it *suspends* the execution of your program. After typing Control-Z, if you type the `jobs` command, it will show your suspended program. Typing `fg` will cause it to resume and continue accepting input -- until you signal an end-of-file condition by typing Control-D. That would be easier to see if your program generated some output.

The behavior of Control-Z isn't connected to the way your program is written; Control-Z will suspend (nearly) *any* running program, whether it's written in C or not, and whether it's waiting for input or not. That behavior is specific to Linux and other Unix-like operating systems.

You'll probably never run out of [doubts and questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2429/12541); I certainly haven't.

Comment: @Keith : Thank you for your time and response. Sir, your answer has really helped a lot.So it means that there is only one EOF in linux and that is ctrl+d.Your answer also sums up why I was taken back into the program itself instead of the source code when I used fg with ctrl+z. Thank you very much for the tip on English as well .

Comment: @Ravi.y: It's more indirect than that. Control-D is not `EOF`. Typing Control-D when a program is waiting for input triggers an end-of-file condition, which causes the `getchar()` function to return the special value `EOF` (which is typically equal to `-1`). An I/O error also causes `getchar()` to return `EOF`; you can distinguish between end-of-file and an error (*after* `gethchar()` has returned `EOF`) using the `feof()` and `ferror()` functions. Yes, Control-D is the only input in Linux that triggers an end-of-file condition. (You can use `stty` to reconfigure that -- but don't.)

Comment: @Ravi.y: You're welcome. I've added a link regarding "doubt" usage to the end of my answer.

Comment: I went through that link but still couldn't decide whether the usage is incorrect.My personal opinion is that we learn English to communicate with people around the world.Now if our usage creates ambiguity then it would be appropriate for us to correct it.Here in India , the word "doubt" is used for "uncertainty\question" and its widely(99.9%) used. Its always good of people like you to point out such things. I have edited this question and will keep in mind the difference between "doubt" and "question". Thank you again, Sir.

Comment: @Ravi.y: I've removed the last paragraph of my answer and added it as a comment, since it's not directly relevant to what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

1. CTRL+Z in Windows and CTRL+D in Linux **sends** EOF value to stdin, EOF itself is implementation defined. Only CTRL+D in linux works. You can print it like `printf("%d", EOF);` to see its numerical value.
2. Yes, doubts and thoughts always useful =)

Comment: @Jlghtuse:thank you for your response and time , can you please tell me what does ctrl+z do then ? is not an eof in linux? because the program still stopped when i used it. isn't thats what an EOF supposed to do ?

Comment: CTRL-Z causes a process to suspend in linux.  It basically pauses your program and sends you back to the command line.  But the program has not completed.  If you type `fg` at the prompt, it will resume, without having seen an EOF.

Comment: @Ravi.y, Ctrl+Z is just a key combination. In Windows it sends to program EOF, in Linux it stops process as AShelly says. Key combination for sending EOF in Linux is Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 0):

EOF in C is a condition("End of File), not a special character telling you that you have reached the end - there is no more input. This condition is indicated to you by various functions such as getchar() returning the special value EOF. EOF is just a value (often a macro that is #defined to be -1), that otherwise cannot occur in the data you read by these functions.

If you read from a file, or a pipe, you know you've reached the end of that file when getchar() returns EOF. getchar() reads from stdin. You can have a pipe connected to stdin instead of your console by running your program as `echo hello | ./theprogram`

If you read input from a terminal/console, things are more complex. On some system there are [huge layers](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) involved in bringing input from your keyboard into your program.

But the short version is that on some systems, when you hit the CTRL+D (or CTRL+Z on others) key combination, it's able to notify your program that the end of input is reached, which makes getchar() return EOF.

As for CTRL+z on linux, this would suspend(halt, but not terminate) the current foreground process.